# Ruby on Rails find records through last association records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

User `has_many` operations.
How I can find `Users` and what is the best way to find where:
`User.operations.last.exp_date` > `CurrentDate`?

Comment: you can try this `User.operations.where("exp_date > #{CurrentDate}) is CurrentDate is an variable?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you need, and show us what you tried so far.

Comment: In original I need to find Users with last operation that was more than 10 days. Operations are sorted by created_at, so I think that I need to check last operation of each user. But I do not know best way to write query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna assume that operations are ordered by date anyways, meaning when a new operation is inserted it will not be older than an already inserted record, if so this will work very easily.

```
User.joins(:operations)
  .merge(
    Operation.where('exp_date > ?', Date.today)
  )
```

Comment: irb(main):067:0> BonusCard.joins(:bonus_card_operations).merge(BonusCardOperation.where(value: 100 ))
PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT "bonus_cards".* FROM "bonus_cards" INNER JOIN "bonus_card_operations" ON "bonus_card_operations"."bonus_card_id" = "bonus_cards"."id" AND (bonus_card_operations.tenant_id = 11) WHERE (bonus_cards.tenant_id = 11) AND (bonus_card_operations.tenant_id = 11) AND "bonus_card_operations"."value" = $1

Comment: thank you for your example, I understand your idea. Yes my records are ordered by date. But I had an error(

Comment: I don't know if this is an issue with `merge` and postgres or what, but in this specefic case the query is simple, you could do `BonusCard.joins(:bonus_card_operations).where(bonus_card_operations: { value: 100 })` , check if this works

Comment: BonusCard.joins(:bonus_card_operations).where(bonus_card_operations: { value: 100 })
PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT "bonus_cards".* FROM "bonus_cards" INNER JOIN "bonus_card_operations" ON "bonus_card_operations"."bonus_card_id" = "bonus_cards"."id" AND (bonus_card_operations.tenant_id = 11) WHERE (bonus_cards.tenant_id = 11) AND "bonus_card_operations"."value" = $1

Comment: where does that `11` come from?

Comment: it is milia gem for multi tenancy, 11 - it tenant_id for my account

Comment: Sorry, my fail. I don't reload console for a long time(

Comment: I'm interesting for the future, how it to do if records will not be ordered?

Comment: The hardest part is that you said the `latest record` this is kinda hard even with raw sql, it could be solved but it would require more than a single query, a query to get all the last record, then remove the ones that don't meet the date requirement, then get the users, i can't think of a more optimised way at the moment.

Comment: what i mean by hard, is cause the user might have a record that matches the date criteria, but it isn't the last operation he made, and the last operation doesn't meet the restriction, so if you use this current answer, it will return that user, even though it doesn't match the full criteria

Comment: last my question: is it will be better for optimization to make additional date field ( last_operataion_date ) in BonusCards table, and fill it through operations_controller ?

Comment: yea that would make querying easier, if you do this query a lot then it would make some good improvement, but you'll need to make sure that you update that field correctly every time.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by,

```
user.operations.where("exp_date > ?", CurrentDate)
```

Comment: this will do: undefined method `operations' for #<Class:0x007fc855c7ccc8>

Comment: its is giving this issue because u dont have user object.First find user object by user = User.find(user_id)